# PYTHON: ¿Cómo gráficar un circulo con matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Quiero graficar (x-2)^2+y^2 = 4 haciendo uso de python, Este es mi código:

```
def f(x):
   y=math.sqrt(4-((x-2)**2))
   return(y)


x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 10)
plt.plot(x, f(x), color="red", markersize=1) 

plt.title("Circulos")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Evidentemente, plt.plot necesita el parametro x y el parametro y. 
Por lo tanto despejo la ecuación antes mencionada ( (x-2)^2+y^2 = 4)
de lo cual obtengo: 
y = sqrt(4-(x-2)^2) Pero evidentemente el (x-2)^2 crece más que 4 por lo tanto obtengo algo negativo y evidentemente no hay raíz negativa. 
Quisiera saber si ¿hay otra forma de hacerlo? 
Si saco la raíz obtengo y = 2-(x-2) pero eso ya no corresponde a un circulo sino a una ecuación lineal. ¡Ayuda!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`y = sqrt(4-((x-2)**2))` solo da valores positivos para `y`. Y solo está definido bien cuando `x` sería entra 0 y 4. De este modo, solo se puede dibujar la mitad de un círculo. La otra mitad sería `y = -sqrt(4-((x-2)**2))`.

En código:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    # mejor emplear el sqrt de numpy y no de math, para hacer el sqrt de toda la lista de `x`
    y = np.sqrt(4 - ((x - 2) ** 2))
    return y

num_puntos = 10
# x solo puede tener valores entre 0 y 4
x = np.linspace(0, 4, num_puntos)

# dibuja el circulo con lineas cortas
plt.plot(x, f(x), color="red", markersize=1)
# dibuja los puntos x,y calculados
plt.plot(x, f(x), 'bo')
# opcionalmente, dibuja la otra mitad del circulo
# plt.plot(x, -f(x), color="red", markersize=1)

plt.title("Circulos")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
# para que parece un círculo y no un ovalo, los ejes `x` e `y` tienen que tener el mismo 'aspect ratio'
# es decir, cada distancia en `x` tiene que equivaler la misma distancia en `y`
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: resultado]

Empleando `cos` y `sin` variando un ángulo entre 0 y 2 π se puede crear un círculo con cada segmento del mismo tamaño:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

num_segmentos = 20
rad = 2
cx = 2
cy = 0

angulo = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_segmentos+1)
x = rad * np.cos(angulo) + cx
y = rad * np.sin(angulo) + cy

plt.plot(x, y, color="red", markersize=1)
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')

plt.title("Circulos")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: resultado con cos y sin]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, no había notado lo del intervalo de 0 a 4. Agradezco mucho tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt import numpy as np

# Definir el radio del círculo

R = 2

# Definir el ángulo de 0 a 2*pi theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

# Calcular las coordenadas x y y del objeto en función

del ángulo

x = R* np.cos(theta) y = R * np.sin(theta)

# Graficar el círculo

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.axis('equal')

plt.xlabel('Posición x') plt.ylabel('Posición y')

plt.title('Movimiento Rectilíneo Circular')

plt.grid(True) plt.show()
```